# running pm2 as part of crontab script

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a crontab command set up like below

> */2 * * * * cd dir && dir/keepalive.ksh qa >> /var/log/test/keepalive.log

the keepalive.sh script essentially calls a start script with 'test' argument which executes the following script

```
print "Start the following proccesses"
if [ ${ENV} == "qa" ]
then
    dir="my path"
    print "Start QA Server"
    pm2 start ${dir}/server.js -- app-env=qa db-env=qa
fi
exit
```

Problem: The pm2 command never starts up the process. I also tried to use the full path of pm2 (/usr/local/bin/pm2) but still no luck. I can see the output of the print statements which means the script is getting executed as expected.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Just a guess, but what is wrong might be logged to stderr rather than stdout. Your keepalive.log is only capturing stdout (I imagine). Rewrite your crontab to log both stdout and stderr so you can see what is going wrong.

Comment: hmm that didn't work. its weird cause I cannot figure out if the pm2 command even runs due to inadequate logs

Comment: What user does cron run your script as? I'm guessing it's no whom you expect.

Comment: its the correct user. when I extracted out the pm2 command from the script and put something like this without the brackets in the cron it worked

[ * * * * * /var/lib/node && /var/lib/pm2 && pm2 run something >> log ]

Guessing it is something to do with node and pm2 being not set in the PATH

Comment: note: pm2 has an inbuilt cron feature as described in [this link](https://serverfault.com/a/1059161) - `pm2 restart 0 --cron "*/10 * * * *"`

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the similar problem before and it turned out I need to prepend the pm2 command with the exact path to my node executable like this

```sh
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/pm2 start myapp.js
```

So in your case, you can try

```sh
/path/to/node /usr/local/bin/pm2 start ${dir}/server.js -- app-env=qa db-env=qa
```

Where `/path/to/node` needs to be replaced with the output of `which node` in your terminal.

Comment: It's a very useful answer for me